# What is relation between ECMA Script, Angular and Type Script?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecma

I would like to know **relation between ECMA Script, Angular and Type Script**.

If **Angular 8** use **TypeScript 3.4** then 
which version of **ECMAScript** can be used in **Angular 8**?

Kindly help me.
I appreciate all responses.Thanks ahead.

Comment: TS is a superset of JS. It conforms to ES inasmuch as it will not have directly conflicting syntax. But TS just *produces* JS code, it isn't running, so it doesn't need to conform to the ES standard. So, if your project uses TS it will conform to the ES spec *you tell it* - the compiler understands TS code and knows what logic you want to implement. It produces JS to satisfy that logic but can produce the ES5 or ES6 or ES2019 level syntax or whatever you configure it to. Angular is completely orthogonal to TS/JS aside from TS/JS implementing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. but i m new in angular, find hard to understand you answer. If you help me out to elaborate more .

Comment: Angular doesn't use ECMAScript at all. It uses Typescript. Typescript and Angular together are latter compiled TO ECMAScript/Javascript.

Comment: @ritaj So, Can we not able to use ECMA 10 into angular?

Answer (score 5):

1. **ECMA Script** is the standard for writing **Javascript**.
2. **Type Script** is just the superset of **ECMA Script** i.e.all ECMA Script functionality + some extra functionality(type checking, interface etc.).
3. Angular2+ use **Type Script** syntax.**But at the end everything is converted into javascript(By transpiler)** i.e. angular at the end uses **transpiler** to convert to convert **typeScript** code into pure **ECMA script**.

Comment: Thank you so much,  Can I use ECMA 10 into angular coding?